# What is the difference between literal and variables in Python?

Tags: python, variables, definition, literals

I'm a beginner user for Python, but I get confused between literal and variables.

This is what I know about a literal: `"a"+"b"`

And variables: `sentence="a"+"b"`

Comment: You should really read the [Python Tutorial](http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial) at least.

Comment: `"a"` and `"b"` are literals. `"a" + "b"` is an expression

Comment: A variable is something that can vary. A literal is stating it literally!

Answer (score 20):

A literal is notation for representing a fixed (`const`) value.
A variable is storage location associated with a symbolic name (pointed to, if you'd like).

It's best explained in use:

```
foo = bar(42)
^     ^   ^
|     |   |--- literal, 42 is *literally* 42
|     |------- function, also represents "something" in memory
|------------- variable, named "foo", and the content may vary (is variable)
```

Identifier on the other hand is the name assigned to a variable in a python statement.

Answer (score 6):

In any programming language a Literal is a constant value, where as identifiers can change their values. Identifiers can store literals and process them further. Identifiers are name given to variables.

`1`, `1.5`, `'a'`, `"abc"`, etc. are examples for literals. But in the statement `x=123`, x is a variable and 123 is a Literal.

Comment: An identifier is not a variable. An identifier may be the *name* of a variable.