# How are arguments resolved when executing a file using subprocess.call in Python?

Tags: python, subprocess, exe

I would like to execute an .exe file from a Python script, on Windows, with a bunch of arguments. Part of those arguments are the paths to input files and outputs.

My question: can I save the paths in a variable, which I then use as an argument, or does the call take only the name of the argument instead of its value?

My idea:

```
outputPath = C:\...\folder1\folder2
inputpath = D:\...\folder1\folder2
subprocess.call('runnable.exe', outputPath, inputPath)
```

instead of

```
subprocess.call('runnable.exe', C:\...\folder1\folder2, D:\...\folder1\folder2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do something like this

```
from subprocess import Popen
outputPath ='C:\...\folder1\folder2'
inputpath = 'D:\...\folder1\folder2'
command='ruunable.exe' + outputPath + inputpath
proc=Popen(command)
```

Answer (score 1):

The call function, like every other function and method in Python, takes variables or literals as arguments. See [What is the difference between literal and variables in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16116446/what-is-the-difference-between-literal-and-variables-in-python#16116487) for more details on those. You may also consider reading through the [Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html). It can give you a great introduction to programing in Python.